# Public directory not found (404) ExpressJS and Jade

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I already serve the static files using this.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This is my index.jade sample

```
// jQuery
script(src='public/js/jquery.min.js')
// jQuery Easing
script(src='public/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js')
// Bootstrap
script(src='public/js/bootstrap.min.js')
// Waypoints
script(src='public/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js')
// Stellar Parallax
script(src='public/js/jquery.stellar.min.js')
// Counter
script(src='public/js/jquery.countTo.js')
// Magnific Popup
script(src='public/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js')
script(src='public/js/magnific-popup-options.js')
// Google Map
script(src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCefOgb1ZWqYtj7raVSmN4PL2WkTrc-KyA&sensor=false')
script(src='public/js/google_map.js')
// For demo purposes only styleswitcher ( You may delete this anytime )
script(src='public/js/jquery.style.switcher.js')
```

Here is my structure.

[image]

Here is the error on my console.

[image]

Can anyone help me identify the problem here? That would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Remove `public` from `urls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script(src='/js/jquery.min.js')` is enough. You don't need to specify `public` in the URLs.